# FactoryGirl: attributes_for not giving me associated attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a Code model factory like this:

```
Factory.define :code do |f|
    f.value "code"
    f.association :code_type
    f.association(:codeable, :factory => :portfolio)
end
```

But when I test my controller with a simple test_should_create_code like this:

```
  test "should create code" do
    assert_difference('Code.count') do
      post :create, :code => Factory.attributes_for(:code)
    end
    assert_redirected_to code_path(assigns(:code))
  end
```

... the test fails.  The new record is not created.

In the console, it seems that `attributes_for` does not return all required attributes like the create does.

```
rob@compy:~/dev/my_rails_app$ rails console test
Loading test environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> Factory.create(:code)
=> #<Code id: 1, code_type_id: 1, value: "code", codeable_id: 1, codeable_type: "Portfolio", created_at: "2011-02-24 10:42:20", updated_at: "2011-02-24 10:42:20">
irb(main):002:0> Factory.attributes_for(:code)
=> {:value=>"code"}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
(Factory.build :code).attributes.symbolize_keys
```

Check this: http://groups.google.com/group/factory_girl/browse_thread/thread/a95071d66d97987e)

Comment: This has the unwanted side-effect of returning timestamps, id, etc... Not really a solution for all problems

Comment: @coneybeare: there's a simple fix for that.  See the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290286/factorygirl-why-does-attributes-for-omit-some-attributes

Comment: Not work for me: it shows "MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, created_at, updated_at.."

Answer (score 10):

This one doesn't return timestamps etc., only attributes that are accessible for mass assignment:

```
(FactoryGirl.build :position).attributes.symbolize_keys.reject { |key, value| !Position.attr_accessible[:default].collect { |attribute| attribute.to_sym }.include?(key) }
```

Still, it's quite ugly. I think FactoryGirl should provide something like this out of the box.

I opened a request for this [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/408).

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest yet an other approach, which I think is clearer:

```
attr = attributes_for(:code).merge(code_type: create(:code_type))
```

Comment: You can also do `attributes_for(:code).merge(code_type_attributes: attributes_for(:code_type))`

Answer (score 2):

heres what I end up doing...

```
conf = FactoryGirl.build(:conference)
post :create, {:conference => conf.attributes.slice(*conf.class.accessible_attributes) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've synthesized what others have said, in case it helps anyone else. To be consistent with the version of FactoryGirl in question, I've used Factory.build() instead of FactoryGirl.build(). Update as necessary.

```
def build_attributes_for(*args)
  build_object = Factory.build(*args)
  build_object.attributes.slice(*build_object.class.accessible_attributes).symbolize_keys
end
```

Simply call this method in place of Factory.attributes_for:

```
post :create, :code => build_attributes_for(:code)
```

The full gist (within a helper module) is here: https://gist.github.com/jlberglund/5207078

Answer (score 0):

In my APP/spec/controllers/pages_controllers_spec.rb I set:

```
let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:page).merge(subject: FactoryGirl.create(:theme), user: FactoryGirl.create(:user)) }
```

Because I have two models associated. This works too:

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :page do
       title      { Faker::Lorem.characters 12 }
       body       { Faker::Lorem.characters 38 }
       discution  false
       published  true
       tags       "linux, education, elearning"
       section   { FactoryGirl.create(:section) }
       user      { FactoryGirl.create(:user)    }                                                                                                                            
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. You probably want to omit the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes.

`FactoryGirl.build(:car).attributes.except('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at').symbolize_keys`

Limitations:

- It does not generate attributes for HMT and HABTM associations (as these associations are stored in a join table, not an actual attribute).
- Association strategy in the factory must be `create`, as in `association :user, strategy: :create`. This strategy can make your factory very slow if you don't use it wisely.