# FactoryGirl build attributes with sequence returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a very simple factory with sequence

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :lecture do
    sequence(:name) {|n| "lecture #{n}" }
    sequence(:slug) {|n| "lecture-#{n}" }
  end
end
```

When I `build` it - it looks fine

```
(FactoryGirl.build :lecture)
=> #<Lecture id: nil, slug: "lecture-20", name: "lecture 20", position: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

but when I try to access the `attributes`, I only get `nil` values

```
(FactoryGirl.build :lecture).attributes
=> {"name"=>nil,
 "slug"=>nil,
 "id"=>nil,
 "position"=>nil,
 "created_at"=>nil,
 "updated_at"=>nil}
```

When I use another factory without a sequence, it works fine. Also, using `attributes_for` works fine

```
FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:lecture)
=> {:name=>"lecture 23", :slug=>"lecture-23"}
```

I'd like to be able to use `build` so I get all attributes, [including foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294322/305019), but somehow it returns `nil` values... Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: I dont have any problems with getting the attributes values of a built factory using sequence. What version of FactoryGirl do you use?

Comment: 4.1.0, which should be the latest (and using Rails 3.2.9). At least this is what I'm getting when issuing those commands in `pry` from inside an rspec test... Maybe it's not the sequence that is causing this, but something else, but the factory is exactly as I posted.

Comment: It would help to see your model code.  Does the same thing happen if you don't use factory_girl?  eg something like: `Lecture.new(slug: "foo").attributes`

Comment: I asked this question in early 2013. Trying it now it seems to work as expected. Maybe it was something to do with the model (which must have changed since). Thanks for the suggestion though.