# Factory Girl Association Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a very simple association set up in FactoryGirl, but it's not working for some reason.  The app is for a tour company, so each Tour has a Destination (I'm using ActiveRecord, so the `Tour` model `belongs_to` a `Destination` -- this association is required for all tours).  So I set up my factories like this:

```
# spec/factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :destination do
    name "Example Destination"
    city "Example City"
    state "CA"
  end

  factory :tour do
    departure_date { 1.day.from_now }
    return_date { 1.day.from_now }
    destination
  end
end
```

However, when I call `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:tour)`, it returns:

```
{:departure_date => Mon, 04 Nov 2013 17:51:26 UTC +00:00,
 :return_date    => Mon, 04 Nov 2013 17:51:26 UTC +00:00}
```

No `destination_id`!  Why?

The `destination` factory works just fine.

I tried defining the association the old way `association :destination, factory: :destination`, but that didn't help.  I can get it to work if I manually define the `destination_id` as `destination_id FactoryGirl.create(:destination).id`, but I shouldn't have to do that.  Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Why not do `destination nil` if you don't want to assign anything initially.

Comment: I do want to assign destination -- `destination_id` is required for all `tours`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attributes_for` doesn't doesn't load associated objects. It only generates attributes for the object that you're requesting.

To get it to load the associated `destination`, use `build` or `create` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The attributes_for doesn't create the associations attributes (by design I believe). This should work:

```
FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:tour, :destination_attributes => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:destination))
```

But, this might be a slicker solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294322/632735

:)

Comment: Would my `tour` model need to accept nested attributes for `destination` for that to work? Because it's not working for me ("unknown attribute: destination_attributes").  Thanks for the link though! Very helpful.  If you edit the answer, I'll give you an upvote

Comment: Have you got attr_accessible :destination_attributes in your Tour model? That should sort it :)

Comment: The problem with this is that `attributes_for` does not persist either the record, thus the `destination_id` is never generated.

Comment: Yep, good point Chris and Nathan was specifically looking for a destination_id so I guess attributes_for wouldn't help much in this case.