# factory_girl new instance inherit parent id of associated class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am having some tests fail because of difficulty setting up factory_girl. I have a class JOB and a class TEMPLATE. There is also a PROVIDER user class. A job belongs_to both a JOB and a TEMPLATE. However, my current factory assigns a provider and template separately.

THIS ONE BREAKS:

```
  expect { post :create, job: attributes_for(:job, provider_id: provider.id) }.to change(Job,:count).by(1)
```

THIS ONE WORKS (MANUALLY DEFINE):

```
  expect { post :create, job: attributes_for(:job, provider_id: provider.id, template_id: create(:template, provider_id: provider.id) ) }.to change(Job,:count).by(1)
```

Is there any way to set up the factory to have the template automatically be created as belonging to the provider?

```
  factory :job do
    provider
    template
  end

  factory :template do
    template_type { Faker::Lorem.word }
    template_text { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(3) }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your description, a template should also refer to the created provider. You could do this writing something like

```
factory :job do
  provider

  after(:build) do |job|
    job.template = build(:template, provider: job.provider)
  end
end
```

You can read about this in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks

Comment: thats kind of what I had though when I read through the documentation. For whatever, it still is breaking the tests... not sure if it's related to the factory?

Comment: even RSpec can be debugged: just start the debugger in your controller create action and see what it does: is the created job valid? job.valid? does the job. If not, check what errors are in there: job.errors does the job. Often the easiest way to find out why a test is failing...

Comment: thanks... in the create method of the controller, "@job = Job.new(job_params)"; job_params is sending in a provider_id, but not the template_id... since the template_id is required, it fails. should the factory be before(:create)?

Comment: No, the reason is that attributes_for does not return associations, as described in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/450

Answer (score 0):

To deal with attributes_for not returning associations, you could define your own attributes_for, including these as well. I once wrote a custom, pretty complicated method including all "accessible" associations. I will include it here, in case you want to use it

```
# In contrast with "attributes_for", "attributes_for_incl_associations" does return attributes 
# for accessible associations as well
# Inspired by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290286/factorygirl-why-does-attributes-for-omit-some-attributes
def attributes_for_incl_associations(*args)
  obj = FactoryGirl.build(*args); klass = obj.class

  # Find all accessible attributes in object's class
  if defined? controller and controller.current_user and klass.active_authorizers.include? controller.current_user.role
    accessible = klass.accessible_attributes(controller.current_user.role)
  else
    accessible = klass.accessible_attributes(:default)
  end

  # Find all associations in object's class
  associations = klass.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map { |a| "#{a.name}_id" }

  # Find all accessible associations in the created object's attributes
  accessible_associations = obj.attributes.delete_if do |k, v| 
    !accessible.include?(k) || !associations.member?(k) 
  end

  # Remove all attributes from FactoryGirl attributes that are not accessible
  factory_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(*args).delete_if do |k, v|
    !accessible.include?(k)
  end

  # Merge FactoryGirl attributes with accessible associations
  factory_attributes.merge(accessible_associations.symbolize_keys)
end
```