# Where are my FactoryGirl Association Attributes Going?

Tags: factory-bot

I have the following FactoryGirl structures:

```
trait :basic_asset_attributes do
  association :organization, :factory => :transit_agency
end

trait :vehicle_attributes do
  basic_asset_attributes
  vin "1FMDU34E5XZ464008"
end

factory :bus, :class => :vehicle do
  vehicle_attributes
  seating_capacity 40
end
```

My `organization` is built like so:

```
factory :organization do
  customer_id 1
  address1 '123 Fake St'
  city 'Fakesville'
  state 'PA'
  zip '17120'
  url 'http://www.example.com'
  phone '9999999999'
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Org #{n}" }

  factory :transit_agency, class: TransitAgency do
  end
end
```

and `FactoryGirl.build(:transit_agency).valid?` returns `true`

However, when I call `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:bus), I get the following:

```
{:vin=>"1FMDU34E5XZ464008",
 :seating_capacity=>40,
}
```

What happened to my organization association?  It's valid, so why isn't

Comment: possible duplicate of [FactoryGirl: why does attributes\_for omit some attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290286/factorygirl-why-does-attributes-for-omit-some-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/450) that this is by design.

From that issue:

> Because of the complexity of handling different nesting and various cases, along with the common use case (controller specs) often wanting to specify FKs directly, attributes_for does not handle associations

Thought they go on to say:

> Although there is complexity surrounding managing associations and
>   data, that doesn't mean you're out of luck; you can write your own
>   strategy (or modify FactoryGirl's) on a per-project basis to get the
>   desired functionality.
>
> To override FactoryGirl's attributes_for, you can do:

```
# spec/support/factory_girl/custom_attributes_for.rb
class CustomAttributesFor
  def association(runner)
    runner.run(:create)
  end

  def result(evaluation)
    evaluation.object.attributes # this assumes your instance responds to attributes and returns a hash, which AR::Base subclasses will do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.register_strategy(:attributes_for, CustomAttributesFor)
```