# FactoryGirl attributes_for method not returning foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have two models, Show and Venue. A Venue `has_many :shows`. A show `belongs to :venue`. They are defined as follows:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :shows
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :show_date, presence: true
  validates :doors_open, presence: true
  validates :dinner_starts, presence: true
  validates :dinner_ends, presence: true
  validates :show_starts, presence: true
  validates :show_ends, presence: true
  validates :venue, presence: true

  belongs_to :venue, foreign_key: 'venue_id'
end
```

with schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150218021116) do

  create_table 'shows', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date 'show_date'
    t.time 'doors_open'
    t.time 'dinner_starts'
    t.time 'dinner_ends'
    t.time 'show_starts'
    t.time 'show_ends'
    t.datetime 'created_at',    null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at',    null: false
    t.integer 'venue_id'
  end

  add_index 'shows', ['venue_id'], name: 'index_shows_on_venue_id'

  create_table 'venues', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    t.datetime 'created_at', null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', null: false
  end

end
```

and factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :show do
    show_date Faker::Date.forward 30
    doors_open Faker::Time.forward 30, :evening
    dinner_starts Faker::Time.forward 30, :evening
    dinner_ends Faker::Time.forward 30, :evening
    show_starts Faker::Time.forward 30, :evening
    show_ends Faker::Time.forward 30, :evening

    association :venue, factory: :venue
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :venue do
    name Faker::Address.street_name
  end
end
```

I am trying to test my `shows_controller` by passing it valid attributes, the problem I am running into is that FactoryGirl's `attributes_for` method doesn't return the `venue_id` field. Here is what I get when I run `puts attributes_for`

```
{:show_date=>Tue, 03 Mar 2015, :doors_open=>2015-03-12 17:44:45 -0500, :dinner_starts=>2015-02-25 20:35:13 -0600, :dinner_ends=>2015-03-08 19:58:18 -0500, :show_starts=>2015-02-25 21:25:55 -0600, :show_ends=>2015-03-17 21:21:57 -0500}
```

Did I set something up wrong here? Why am I not getting the `venue_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to get FactoryGirl to generate the foreign key via a reference to the association, I'm wondering if the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association is causing the problem. It looks like the relationship you have here is that a `Venue` simply `has_many` shows; the `Venue` is not dependent on (AKA "belonging to") a show for it's existence (no foreign key for a show in the venues table). See if changing the association clears things up for FactoryGirl.

Comment: hmm, no dice. FatoryGirl is building shows that have a venue, and have a venue_id, but attributes_for does not have a venue

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290286/factorygirl-why-does-attributes-for-omit-some-attributes) might address your problem.