# Associations with Factory Girl in Controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to RSpec, and trying to get my head around using Factory Girl with associations in controller specs.  The difficulty is:

- it's necessary to use "attributes_for" in functional tests
- attributes_for "[elides any associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359)"

So if I have models like this:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :org    
  validates :org, :presence => true
end

class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brands
end
```

And a factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :brand do
    association :org
  end
end
```

This controller spec fails:

```
describe BrandsController do
  describe "POST create with valid params" do
    it "creates a new brand" do
      expect {
        post :create, brand: attributes_for(:brand)
      }.to change(Brand, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

(And if I comment out "validates :org, :presence => true" it passes)

There are a number of solutions suggested and I think I have been making simple errors which have meant that I have not been able to get any of them to work.

1) Changing the factory to org_id per [a suggestion on this page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359) failed a number of tests with "Validation failed: Org can't be blank"

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :brand do
    org_id 1002
  end
end
```

2) Using "symbolize_keys" looks promising.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103572/factorygirl-attributes-for-not-giving-me-associated-attributes) and [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/408) it is suggested to use code like this:

```
(FactoryGirl.build :position).attributes.symbolize_keys
```

I'm not sure how to apply this in my case.  Below is a guess that doesn't work (giving the error No route matches {:controller=>"brands", :action=>"{:id=>nil, :name=>\"MyString\", :org_id=>1052, :include_in_menu=>false, :created_at=>nil, :updated_at=>nil}"}):

```
describe BrandsController do
  describe "POST create with valid params" do
    it "creates a new brand" do
      expect {
        post build(:brand).attributes.symbolize_keys 
      }.to change(Brand, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

**Update**

I almost got this working with Shioyama's answer below but got the error message:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, brand: build(:brand).attributes.symbolize_keys
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
  Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, created_at, updated_at
```

So following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103572/factorygirl-attributes-for-not-giving-me-associated-attributes/11438545#11438545) I changed it to:

```
post :create, brand: build(:brand).attributes.symbolize_keys.reject { |key, value| !Brand.attr_accessible[:default].collect { |attribute| attribute.to_sym }.include?(key) }
```

Which worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution 2), you have not passed an action to `post` which is why it is throwing an error.

Try replacing the code in that `expect` block to:

```
post :create, brand: build(:brand).attributes.symbolize_keys
```

Comment: Thanks again!  I got this working with a twist that I will put in my question.

Comment: Great! Crazy long though just to get it to pass the association id. Would be nice if there was a cleaner way to do it.