# FactoryGirl attributes_for and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm trying to test associations in my Rspec controller tests. Problem is that Factory doesn't produce associations for the attributes_for command. So, following the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103572/factorygirl-attributes-for-not-giving-me-associated-attributes) I defined my validate attributes in my controller spec like so:

```
def valid_attributes
   user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   country = FactoryGirl.create(:country)
   valid_attributes = FactoryGirl.build(:entitlement, user_id: user.id, country_id: country.id, client: true).attributes.symbolize_keys
   puts valid_attributes
end
```

However, when the controller test runs I still get the following errors:

```
 EntitlementsController PUT update with valid params assigns the requested entitlement as @entitlement
    Failure/Error: entitlement = Entitlement.create! valid_attributes
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: User can't be blank, Country can't be blank, Client  & expert are both FALSE. Please specify either a client or expert relationship, not both
```

Yet the the valid_attributes output in the terminal clearly shows that each valid_attribute has a user_id, country_id and expert is set to true:

```
  {:id=>nil, :user_id=>2, :country_id=>1, :client=>true, :expert=>false, :created_at=>nil, :updated_at=>nil}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a `puts` as the last line in your `valid_attributes` method, which returns nil. That's why when you pass it to `Entitlement.create!` you get an error about user and country being blank, etc.

Try removing that `puts` line, so you have just:

```
def valid_attributes
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  country = FactoryGirl.create(:country)
  FactoryGirl.build(:entitlement, user_id: user.id, country_id: country.id, client: true).attributes.symbolize_keys
end
```

Incidentally, you shouldn't really be creating users and countries and then passing their ids to `build`, you can do that in the factory itself just by including lines with `user` and `country` in the `entitlement` factory. When you run `FactoryGirl.build(:entitlement)` it will then automatically create them (but not actually save the `entitlement` record).