# FactoryGirl attributes_for with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

There is the following factory:

```
factory :car do
    name 'Some car'
    engine_value 1.6
    color '#ff0000'
    car_type
    engine_type
    transmission
    drive_type
    material
end
```

As you see there are a lot of associated objects. But code

```
attributes_for(:car)
```

generates only `:name=>"Some car", :engine_value=>1.6, :color=>"#ff0000"}` hash. I need to get a hash with all attributes. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FactoryGirl: why does attributes\_for omit some attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290286/factorygirl-why-does-attributes-for-omit-some-attributes)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103572/factorygirl-attributes-for-not-giving-me-associated-attributes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've run into this same issue and I've used something like

```
build(:car).attributes
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it worked for me

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may want to omit the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes.

`FactoryGirl.build(:car).attributes.except('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')`

If you need the keys to be symbols (as in the keys generated by `attributes_for`):

`FactoryGirl.build(:car).attributes.except('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at').symbolize_keys`

Limitations:

- It does not generate attributes for HMT and HABTM associations (as these associations are stored in a join table, not an actual attribute).
- Association strategy in the factory must be `create`, as in `association :user, strategy: :create`. This strategy can make your factory very slow if you don't use it wisely.